# Proving ratios using the angle bisector theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles

> In $\triangle ABC$, $BE$ and $CF$ are the angular bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ meeting at $I$. Prove that $\frac{AF}{FI}=\frac{AC}{CI}$.

By the angle bisector theorem we have $\frac{AC}{AE} = \frac{CB}{BE}$ and $\frac{AB}{AF} = \frac{BC}{FC}$. How do I proceed after this? Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AI$ is an angle bisector of $\angle A$, so by the angle bisector theorem, $\frac{AF}{AC} = \frac{FI}{IC}$. This easily rearranges to the required result.

Comment: Can you clarify how the angle bisector theorem helps in deriving the above mentioned result?

Comment: Look at the statement of the angle bisector theorem given [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem). This is exactly the result I have used.

Comment: Oh so you're applying this on $\triangle AEC$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you mean $AFC$, but yes.

Comment: $AEC$ is a line, since $BE$ is the bisector of $\angle B$, so $E$ lies on $AC$. Hence $AEC$ is a line and $AFC$ is a triangle.

Comment: Yes, I got E and F mixed up